# How to fix "listen EACCES: permission denied 0.0.0.0:8000"

Tags: quasar-framework

I tried to explore Quasar Framework. I download node.js and quasar.cli already. i managed to create project, but when i "quasar dev" in my quasar file, it pop up the errors.

C:\Users\User>cd njir

C:\Users\User\njir>quasar dev

Dev mode.......... spa
 Pkg quasar........ v1.2.2
 Pkg @quasar/app... v1.2.1
 Debugging......... enabled

app:quasar-conf Reading quasar.conf.js +0ms
 app:dev Checking listening address availability (0.0.0.0:8080)... +25ms

app:dev ⚠️  Unknown network error occurred +0ms
{ [  Error: listen EACCES: permission denied 0.0.0.0:8080

- next_tick.js:63 process._tickCallback
  internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19
- loader.js:834 Function.Module.runMain
  internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:834:11
- node.js:283 startup
  internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19
- node.js:622 bootstrapNodeJSCore
  internal/bootstrap/node.js:622:3

]
  code: 'EACCES',
  errno: 'EACCES',
  syscall: 'listen',
  address: '0.0.0.0',
  port: 8080 }

C:\Users\User\njir>

Answer (score 21):

For Windows users, please follow these steps:

1. Make sure to run PowerShell as an administrator.
2. Execute the following command to stop the "winnat" service:

`net stop winnat`

3. Execute the following command to restart the "winnat" service:

`net start winnat`

Comment: This fixed the issue for me when trying to run a NextJS app on Windows

Comment: This really fixed the issue for me. Thanks, Jamal for the solution.

Comment: If anyone is trying to open up a specific port run this after net stop winnat
`netsh int ipv4 add excludedportrange protocol=tcp startport=1143 numberofports=1` 
Replace 1143 with whatever port you are trying to use and change tcp to udp as needed.

Answer (score 2):

I recently had this error and it resolved when I restarted my machine.

If that doesn't work for you I would try port 80 as a quick check to see if it is a problem with a closed port. Port 80 is for HTTP so it should be open.

quasar dev -p 80

If that works, then port 8080 might not be setup to run your local server.

To check port availability I use nmap (https://nmap.org/). If you install it and want to check a port from the command line run something like:

nmap localhost -p 8080

Answer (score 2):

Port 8080 was not available in network , issue could be resolved by updating dev property in quasar.config.js

```
devServer: {
      // https: true,
      //port: 8080,
      open: true // opens browser window automatically
    },
```

Uncomment port and change the default port number, for e.g. port: 8089

Answer (score -1):

Restarting my computer helped me solve this problem.